# function DayOfWeekAsString alternative

Tags: coldfusion

I am using the function `DayOfWeekAsString` in my script which returns the complete day name.

I am looking for some function which delivers the day name like "SA, SU, MO, TU,..."

Is there a predefined function available?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is nothing built in to do that but this should do it:

```
uCase( left( dayOfWeekAsString( 1 ), 2 ) )
```

Comment: For what it's worth, `dateFormat(someDate,"ddd")` returns the three-letter abbreviation for the day.

Comment: You would still have to use `uCase( left( dateFormat(someDate,"ddd"), 2 ) )` to get an upper case 2 letter abbreviation though